# Including a generic type parameter in interface, constraint by an interface

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I am stuck on the usage of an implementation that is constraint by an interface.  My usage is intuitive to me, but does not compile so I am misunderstanding something.

My interfaces:

```c
interface IEntity
{
    int ExampleMethod(IContext<IFooBar> context);
}

interface IContext<T> where T : class, IFooBar
{
    T FooBar { get; set; }
}

interface IFooBar
{
    int Value { get; }
}
```

My implementations:

```c
class Entity : IEntity
{
    public int ExampleMethod(IContext<IFooBar> context)
    {
        return context.FooBar.Value;
    }
}

class Context : IContext<FooBar>
{
    public FooBar FooBar { get; set; }
}

class FooBar : IFooBar
{
    public int Value { get { return 10; } }
}
```

Usage of Entity class, where problem is thrown

```c
class UsageOfEntity
{
    public UsageOfEntity()
    {
        var context = new Context();
        var entity = new Entity();

        int result = entity.ExampleMethod(context);
    }
}
```

The usage of instance `context` throws an error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Context' to 'IContext<IFooBar>'

How do I constrain the generic type parameter such that my implementation can be used?

Comment: `Context` is an `IContext<FooBar>` not an `IContext<IFooBar>`. Does `IContext<T>.FooBar` need to be settable? If not, you can make `T` covariant e.g. `interface IContext<out T> where T : class, IFooBar`.

Comment: This *would* make sense if `IContext` did not declare a setter for `FooBar`.

Comment: I think you shoudn't have a `POCO` class as interface. since it adds nothing (`IFooBar`)

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  The property does not need to be settable, so making `T` covariant works for me.  I need to educate myself on what the difference is between covariance and contravariance so I don't make this mistake again.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay feel free to post this an answer and I will accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Context` is an `IContext<FooBar>` not an `IContext<IFooBar>`.

Because the OP has indicated in the comments that `IContext<T>.FooBar` only needs to be read-only, `T` can be made covariant:

```
interface IContext<out T>
where T : class, IFooBar
{
    T FooBar { get; }
}
```

Now, because `FooBar` implements `IFoobar`, it is valid to use a `IContext<FooBar>` in place of a `IContext<IFooBar>`:

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are trying to convert `Context` to `Type` `IContext` just as your error tells you.

```
{
    public UsageOfEntity()
    {
        var context = new Context();
        var entity = new Entity();

        int result = entity.ExampleMethod(context);
    }
}
```

You are trying to pass `Context` to `IContext` in this line

```
entity.ExampleMethod(context);
```

You should make the `Type` passed in `ExampleMethod()` `Context<FooBar>`.
I would also like to point out that making an interface for a `POCO` class is unnecessary, just keep it a normal class.

Your code should look like this:

```
class Entity : IEntity
{
    public int ExampleMethod(Context<FooBar> context)
    {
        return context.FooBar.Value;
    }
}

interface IEntity
{
    int ExampleMethod(IContext<IFooBar> context);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, the code block you suggest doesn't compile either. `'Entity' does not implement interface member 'IEntity.ExampleMethod(IContext<IFooBar>)'`.  As to the comment on the `POCO`: my code was just an abstraction on the issue.  In my actual code I have two different implementations of classes, that both are implementations of the same interface.